# Using filter function with minimum and maximum values

Tags: swift

I am trying to sort the items that are in a list with a user inputted min and max.

Code for context:

```
enum Category: Comparable {
    case attack
    case healing
    case support
}

typealias Spell = (name: String, cat: Category, cost: Int)

let startingSpellList: [Spell] = [
    ("Poison", .attack, 3),
    ("Bio", .attack, 26),
    ("Fire", .attack, 4),
    ("Fire 2", .attack, 20),
    ("Fire 3", .attack, 51),
    ("Ice", .attack, 5),
    ("Ice 2", .attack, 21),
    ("Ice 3", .attack, 52),
    ("Bolt", .attack, 6),
    ("Bolt 2", .attack, 22),
    ("Bolt 3", .attack, 53),
    ("Pearl", .attack, 40),
    ("Quake", .attack, 50),
    ("Break", .attack, 25),
    ("Doom", .attack, 35),
    ("Flare", .attack, 45),
    ("Meteor", .attack, 62),
    ("Ultima", .attack, 80),
    
    ("Cure", .healing, 5),
    ("Cure 2", .healing, 25),
    ("Cure 3", .healing, 40),
    ("Regen", .healing, 10),
    ("Life", .healing, 30),
    ("Antidote", .healing, 3),
    ("Remedy", .healing, 15),
    
    ("Imp", .support, 10),
    ("Haste", .support, 10),
    ("Safe", .support, 12),
    ("Shell", .support, 15),
    ("Berserk", .support, 16),
    ("Float", .support, 17),
    ("Reflect", .support, 22),
    ("Quick", .support, 99),
    ("Scan", .support, 3),
    ("Sleep", .support, 5),
    ("Slow", .support, 5),
    ("Mute", .support, 8),
    ("Confuse", .support, 8),
    ("Stop", .support, 10)
]

func spellString(_ spell: Spell) -> String {
    let name = spell.name.padding(toLength: 8, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
    
    let type: String
    switch spell.cat {
    case .attack:
        type = "(Attack) "
    case .healing:
        type = "(Healing)"
    case .support:
        type = "(Support)"
    }
    
    let cost = (spell.cost < 10) ? " " + String(spell.cost) : String(spell.cost)
    
    return "\(name) \(type) - \(cost) MP"
}
```

I want the user to be asked to input a min and max value, and then use the filter higher order function to filter and print all the spells that have an MP(cost) in between those values.

I have tried this:

```
func selectByCost(_ spells: [Spell]) -> [Spell] {
    print("Enter the minimum MP cost: ")
    let min = readLine()!
    print("Enter the maximum MP cost: ")
    let max = readLine()!
    
    if Spell.Int == min...max {
        ???
    }
```

I tried spell.Int= min.max but I get the error that "Value of tuple type 'Spell' (aka '(name: String, cat: Category, cost: Int)') has no member 'Int'"
I am sorry I dont know much about coding if this is a common mistake

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you edit your post with this attempt rather than including it in the comments (where code formatting doesn't work)? Also, I don't see any attempt at using `filter` yet -- what have you tried with that function?

Comment: Yes, Sorry. Let me do that

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with `filter`:

```
func selectByCost(_ spells: [Spell]) -> [Spell] {
    print("Enter the minimum MP cost: ")
    let min = readLine()!
    print("Enter the maximum MP cost: ")
    let max = readLine()!
    
    //You'll have to account for what happens if the user enters invalid numbers
    guard let minNumber = Int(min), let maxNumber = Int(max) else {
        assertionFailure("Not valid numbers")
        return []
    }
    
    //Here's the filter function -- it returns items that meet both criteria
    return spells.filter { $0.cost >= minNumber && $0.cost <= maxNumber }
}
```

If you also check for validity of the range (eg min has to be `<` max), you could do something like this:

```
guard let minNumber = Int(min), let maxNumber = Int(max) else {
    assertionFailure("Not valid numbers")
    return []
}

guard minNumber < maxNumber else {
    assertionFailure("Invalid range")
    return []
}

let range = (minNumber...maxNumber)

return spells.filter { range.contains($0.cost) }
```

Comment: After I input a min and a maximum, nothing prints.

Comment: Did you call `print` with the return value of `selectByCost`? I didn't include any printing in my code because the way you structured it was a function that returns an array.

Comment: no, I didn't. I actually want it to return an array, Do I still print the return value?

Comment: That is completely up to you. If you want it to print, you can print -- if not, you have no requirement to.

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark it as correct with the green checkmark.

Comment: This looks like a well-formed answer to the question. You should accept it. If you can't work out that if you want to print the results, you need to write code to print the results of the call to `selectByCost()`, you might want to step back and work on language fundamentals some more. You might be trying to do more than your current level of knowledge supports.